# DICOM viewer - viewing segmented images

Tags: dicom, papaya

Hi I am using Papaya to view DICOM images. I have a segmented set of DICOM images whose segmented structures I can view using this software called dicomplyer( http://www.dicompyler.com/).

I can see the segmented structures on that software by clicking the structure names. Is this possible using papaya? When I upload the DICOM image set, it says no pixel data found. 
Or is it a problem due to the formatting of the segmented images itself? 
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Please share your DICOM file to help understand the problem better.

Comment: If you mean these are RTStruct, then I can confirm Papaya does not yet support viewing counter-based data, only image voxel data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you the segmented data you are referring to is a DICOM RT Structure Set. This type of file is segmented as a series of contours in patient coordinate space and does not consist of any voxel data.

According to the papaya forum, it isn't currently supported:
http://rii.uthscsa.edu/mango/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=379&sid=2a8c8f942b6fbf3f15b537b5a69a5362

Comment: Thank you @bastula. Would you know if there are any open source web based DICOM RT viewers? that would help.

Comment: Not at the moment. There are other HTML5 based DICOM image viewers like [Cornerstone](https://github.com/chafey/cornerstone), but none support DICOM RT.

I suppose one could write a plugin or contribute the necessary code to make it happen with any of these projects.

The only open source DICOM RT viewer is dicompyler, which you have already used. However it is a desktop application.

Comment: Can we integrate dicomplyer with a web based viewer? Would that be possible @bastula ?

Comment: It can't be integrated in it's current form, but one could port the code from Python to Javascript for one of the above mentioned image viewers.

Comment: I am trying to do that. Would you recommend PyJS for the porting ?

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to answer that, but please feel to contact me offline.

Comment: Sure that would help. Thank you.